# Using USB Tethering with USB-to-Ethernet adapter

Tags: usb-tethering, ethernet

I live in an area without any high-speed internet access. Currently, I am using a cell phone hotspot connected through a wireless-to-wired bridge to my home wired/wireless networks. I would like to increase my bandwidth using multiple cell services/hotspots and have not found the complete answer.

I have a TP-Link ER605 and am able to hook a cellphone directly to the USB WAN port on that device and it works to provide Internet service. I am attempting to connect a second cellphone to an RJ45 WAN port on the ER605 using a USB-to-Ethernet adapter, but have not found any combination that allows the 'USB Tethering' option to be enabled.

I have the following phones:

- TCL 30 XL (Android 12)
- Moto X4 (Android 9)

Both of these devices work to provide Internet service when directly connected to the ER605 with a standard USB cable.

I have tried two USB to Ethernet Adapters:

- uni USB C to Ethernet adapter ([Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C3GHBLB6))
- Smays USB C OTG Ethernet adapter ([Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CMVNC9M))

Neither of these adapters enables the USB Tethering option, either plugged into an ER605 port or to a port on a Windows machine.

What are the cellphone/adapter requirements needed to support this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the requirements:

- USB-OTG Support on the smartphone (my experience across phones is the lower the price, the less likely is the feature range of USB-OTG support)
- Android newer than version 11, this is when the feature was introduced officially in software

This question on Superuser [Android USB Tethering to Router](https://superuser.com/questions/1127972/android-usb-tethering-to-ethernet-to-router) provides two examples from users, who reported them to work:

- Sitecom CN-378 usb-c ethernet adapter
- Cable Matters USB-C multiport adapter